# Use regex stored in a table as criteria for an SQL query

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, join, pattern-matching

I have a table with regular expressions which I need to use to filter rows from another table.
Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
WHERE foo SIMILAR TO '(SELECT regex FROM b)'
```

Obviously, that doesn't work because that isn't the syntax and there are multiple rows in `b` that I need to iterate through.

I'm using PostgreSQL 8.3.

Comment: Post some sample data n desired o/p

Comment: Are you aware that `SIMILAR TO` does *not* use regular expressions, but its own peculiar set of patterns - which are internally rewritten into regular expressions? I recently wrote a [comprehensive answer about that on dba.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)

Comment: You know that pg9.2 has been out for almost a year now, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps doing a join would work? E.g.

```
SELECT a.*, b.regex
  FROM a JOIN b ON a.foo ~ b.regex
```

I'm afraid I'm not familiar enough with Postgres to say for certain, but this would be the ordinary way in SQL of iterating over rows. It should return a.foo multiple times if multiple regexes are matched.